# Unable to download file form JavaScript which is working with href url action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a code where it is working when I use anchor tag the same code when I am trying to call on button click with JQuery it is not downloading the file

```
function DownloadFile() {
    var data = {
        'tableName': $("#tableName").val(),
        'attachmentId': $("#attachmentId").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            
        }
    });
}
```

The same code works with url.action on href tag as follows

```
<a class="mr-2" href="@Url.Action("Index","Document",new { @tableName = "otherVessel",@attachmentId = otherVessel.AttachmentId})"> @otherVessel.AttachmentName</a>
```

My controller code is as follows

```
public ActionResult Index(string tableName, int attachmentId)
{
   AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository = new AttachmentRepository();
   var result = attachmentRepository.GetDocument(tableName, attachmentId);
   var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
   {
     FileName = result.AttachmentName,
     Inline = false,
   };
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
   return File(result.AttachmentData, result.AttachmentType);
}
```

Comment: Obvious question: what's `fileUrl`?

Comment: Did you confirm your `data` value?

Comment: *"not downloading the file"* - do you mean it's not trying to save it to your local machine?   Or do you mean `res` doesn't contain the file you're expecting?  An ajax call won't "download" the file (as in save it)

Comment: fileUrl I set it like this every thing is working but the file is not showing in the download list

Comment: Here is how I set `var fileUrl= "@Url.Action("Index", "Document")";`

Comment: *no showing in the download list* - you mean the browser downloads?  No, because that's not how ajax works - it loads it into your variable `res` (in `success:`)

Comment: Oh k but I would like to download the file any other options